# WPF xaml binding properties on textbox cannot clear

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a textbox binded to one of my viewModel's properties

```
        <TextBox x:Name="box" Height="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding name}"/>
```

viewModel.cs:

```
    public string name { get; set; }
    [...]
    public void clear(){
     name = "";
    }
```

AddCommand: Icommand class:

```
  public void Execute(object parameter){
  //do some stuff
  viewModel.clear();

  }
```

Everything else works perfect. I can read the textbox's and use them to do some calculation in viewModel then bind those calculation to labels to display. But I just cant clear those textbox after I read them. I tried setting the binding to mode=twoway but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell WPF that the property has changed.

something similar to

```
private string _name;
public string name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("name"));
    }
}
```

ofcourse most people would make a base class to avoid having to call that property changed method with so that complicated parameter.

Comment: perfect it worked thanks. what and how do you mean by a base class though?

Comment: @user1294510 take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx this link. A base class would be called something like ViewModelBase and implement the method NotifyPropertyChanged as shown in the example. So that you can just call NotifyPropertyChanged() instead of feeding this + new propertychangedeventargs